# Abrir el archivo mas reciente en una unidad de red

Tags: windows, cmd, batch

¿Hay alguna manera de realizar esta operación usando el vlc? Cuento ya con el código que abre el último archivo reciente en este caso un archivo tanto de video como audio el lío es el siguiente: al realizar esta operación utilizo `pushd` ya que si uso `net` use genera error:

```
pushd \\192.168.1.100\carpeta
    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /od') do set newest=%%a
```

luego planteo:

```
net use  \\192.168.1.100\carpeta /delete
```

o `/d` o `/del` y ninguno funciona, recibo errores.

Comment: `for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /od') do set newest=%%a` ¿Este código está en bash? ¿No falta el `done`?

Comment: Esta realizado en batch

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! cuando decis recibo errores, es muy importante que pongas que errores recibis.

Comment: Después del `pushd` tu directorio actual es la unidad de red. Deberías cambiar de unidad antes de intentar desconectarte.

Comment: ya fue resuelto muchas Gracias, integre scripts de conexion y desconexion desencadenados, Gracias